# Initialize generic object with unknown type

Tags: c#, generics, types

How can I initialize a list containing generic objects whose types can be different?

For example, I have the following:

```
this.Wheres = new List<Where<>>();
```

As you know, <> is not valid syntax. However, sometimes the type passed to Where will be a string and sometimes it will be DateTime, etc. I tried using object as the initialized type, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, you haven't really given enough context (what's SqlWhere?) but normally you'd use a type parameter:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
   private IList<T> wheres;

   public Foo()
   {
       wheres = new List<T>();
   }
}
```

If you want a single collection to contain multiple unrelated types of values, however, you will have to use `List<object>`

Comment: Thanks! And to answer your question, Where is a class in the query builder.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.Wheres = new List<Object>();
```

Comment: This will add (un)boxing and remove type safety.

Comment: How can you prevent that if the list can be composed of different object types??

Comment: This is the right way to do what the OP asked.  Yes, it's not type-safe.  That's not the answer's fault.