# is there any code to retain the value in arraylist in C# when page is refreshed or reloaded

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-webdriver

Is there any way to keep the value in the arraylist even after the page is loaded because I need the stored values for verifying afterwards.

I tried Http Cookie set also but not able to find it. Pls help

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= random2; i++)
            {
                //   int total_checkbox = Total_Count_Checkbox;


                int div = (int)al[i - 1] / 10; //div is the page number of the element
                int mod = (int)al[i - 1] % 10; //mod is checkbox number of the element

                if (mod == 0)       //for checking inf the number comes to be 10
                {
                    div = div - 1;
                    mod = 10;
                }
                if (div == 0)
                {
                    LiSt3[mod - 1].Click();           //Clicking for the same page elements
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int b = 2; b <= div; b++)         //checking for the other pages
                    {
                        Browser.Click("Saved_Estimates", "Forward_Link_normal");
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    }
                    IList<IWebElement> LiSt4 = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".checkbox.checkbox-success.ng-scope"));
                    LiSt4[mod - 1].Click();             //clicking for the other page elements
                }
                Browser.WaitforthePageLoad();
                IList<IWebElement> LiSt_of_Names_Summary_List = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("span[data-bo-bind='item.Name']"));
                IList<IWebElement> LiSt_of_Dates_List = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("span[data-bo-bind='item.GeneratedDateString']"));
                IList<IWebElement> LiSt_of_Times_List = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("span[data-bo-bind='item.GeneratedTimeString']"));
                IList<IWebElement> LiSt_of_Last_Day_Worked_List = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div[data-bo-bind='item.LastDayWorkedDateString']"));
                IList<IWebElement> LiSt_of_Benifit_Commencement_List = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div[data-bo-bind='item.BenefitCommencementDateString']"));
                Browser.WaitforthePageLoad();

                LiSt_of_Names_Summary_List_Arraylist.Add(LiSt_of_Names_Summary_List[mod - 1]);
                LiSt_of_Dates_List_Arraylist.Add(LiSt_of_Dates_List[mod - 1]);
                LiSt_of_Times_List_Arraylist.Add(LiSt_of_Times_List[mod - 1]);
                LiSt_of_Last_Day_Worked_List_Arraylist.Add(LiSt_of_Last_Day_Worked_List[mod - 1]);
                LiSt_of_Benifit_Commencement_List_Arraylist.Add(LiSt_of_Benifit_Commencement_List[mod - 1]);

                if (div != 0)
                {
                    for (int b = 2; b <= div; b++)
                    {
                        Browser.Click("Saved_Estimates", "Back_Arrow_normal");
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: When is this code executed? onpageload? or what? Is it code that executes in response to a user's actions? or does it execute everytime the page is loaded?

Comment: yes on page load, there are 10 options per page and I have to select three from any page randomly. For one iteration it is fine but while another it looses the first value in [0]th index and similarly for the second iteratioonit loosed the [1]st values  too. But I need all the values

Comment: are you saying that a user answers questions on one page, and you need that information saved for the next page load? and so on?

If yes then are you familiar with session variables?

Comment: You can use session or view state for this purpose.
If you can tell me the exact scenario then i can help you in deciding what to use.

Comment: good suggestion i gave huh?

Comment: yes it should save the for the next iteration. I am new to it, I tried it with http cookies but with session I have no idea how to do it for the arraylist. Can u tell it for arraylist too

Comment: If you want to chat offline.. you can send me more information about the project.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily with the help of session.

> Session state enables you to store and retrieve values for a user as
>   the user navigates ASP.NET pages in a Web application. HTTP is a
>   stateless protocol. This means that a Web server treats each HTTP
>   request for a page as an independent request.

For more information for the session go to the following link:
[Session](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)

If you want to store any type into the session you just need to assign it to the session like this

```
ArrayList aryList=new ArrayList();
aryList.Add(Sample);
aryList.Add(Test);
//to store the array list to the session
Session["AryList"] = aryList;
//or if you have a class file then
HttpContext.Current.Session["AryList"] = aryList;
//to get the values from the session
ArrayList aryList= (ArrayList)Session["AryList"];
```

For more help refer to the following question: 
[ArrayList Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820212/arraylist-session)

Hope it will help you.

Comment: is there any predefined namespace for the Session. I tried with System.web but it still showing name "Session" does not present in current context

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969563/session-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context
Go to this answer it will help you.
Or tell me is it a code behind page or a class file?
if the answer is useful to you then mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Use session variables. You can save a wide variety of information this way, or you can be more elaborate and store information in a database.

You can even use AngularJS and JSON objects etc.. depends on how elaborate you want to get.