# What's so bad about ArrayLists?

Tags: c#, arraylist

I'm working on enhancing the platforms in my company and during my research, I've come across a lot of comments from people saying that ArrayLists should be avoided. However, they never gave much explanation why and I can't find any articles about why they're so awful.

Comment: Because they're not generic in C#. http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_Generics_Recipes%E2%80%94Replacing_the_ArrayList_with_Its_Generic_Counterpart

Comment: Also you can't use it in Silverlight

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309694/arraylist-vs-list-in-c-sharp

Comment: If you want something to read the msdn tells you why they introduced them http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5bx6xee.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Arraylists" (also sometimes called "vectors") are perfectly fine data structures; it's just that `ArrayList` is a class that should be avoided in C#.

The reason is that it isn't generic, so you can store any `object` inside it, breaking type-safety.
Use `List<T>` instead.

Comment: This is a good explanation and answer, but a little further clarity is that an ArrayList will allow you to store multiple types of objects in a single ArrayList at the same time. This means you could store string, int, object, etc all in the same ArrayList, so you have to deal with making sure the data type stored is consistent before storage or do type checking on the way out. Either way it is more work for the programmer. Generics are just easier because they do type safety automatically.

Comment: What if you want multiple types of object in a single list? You're writing an 'Asteroids' game and you want to store all Asteroids, Bullets, Player space ship etc. in a single list of GameObjects? Presumably an arraylist would be ok, and you can run operations by looping through the ArrayList and doing if (ArrayList[i] Is SomeInterface)...?

Comment: SLC a generic would still be better. Either store it as List<object> GameObjects or create a class structure that provides for common type. See my above comment about avoiding having to manually handle type safety.

Comment: @SLC In that case you can use `List<object>` or `List<ISomeInterface>`.

Comment: Is `List<object>` really any different from `ArrayList`?

Comment: Is there any impact on performance using ArrayList vs HashSet?

Comment: @user2460328 Depends on whether you need to cast, or box. If List<MyClass> will do the job, then it will perform much better than List<TObject> or ArrayList with a cast for instance.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson that was the answer I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Because they're not strongly typed. They're a bag that can store anything. That means you have to cast when retrieving elements. It also means that there may or may not be boxing/unboxing involved in storing and retrieving values.

Comment: Yes, I get that. What about impact on performance? How does performance of HashSet compare to ArrayList?

Comment: Depends on what you are doing with it. Boxing and unboxing a lot is expensive.

Comment: @user2460328 You shouldn't compare them at all.  A `List` is exactly the same as an `ArrayList` except better.  If you want a list-based structure you use a `List`.  The question of whether to use a `HashSet` or a `List` (which is a valid one) is entirely separate from this discussion, and is based on the type of data you have and how you plan to use it.

Answer (score 1):

They're not generic.  A `List` is exactly the same thing, but it's generic.  This means you're ensuring the objects are all of a common type, and that constraint is enforced by the compiler.  It also avoids boxing of value types.

Answer (score 0):

It's not so much awful as painful. Think of them as List, sort of, ish.

So you have to add a lots of rules to enforce consistency in the collection and use them "everywhere" or deal with the errors that result from having no consistency,"everywhere"

So that a lot of extra code, or you cross your fingers real tight and hope no "dimwit" programmer ever puts something in there you can't deal with.

If your collection could consist of anything, then stick with it, though personally I'd say that if it did, there's almost certainly some sort of major design flaw.