# Declare multi dimensional array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, unity-game-engine

I have this array that I need it to be convert from JS to C#:

```
var allwinning = new Array(
        ["000", "001", "002"],
        ["000", "010", "020"],
        ["000", "011", "022"],
        ["000", "100", "200"],
        ["000", "101", "202"],
        ["000", "110", "220"],
        ["001", "002", "003"],
        ["001", "011", "021"])
```

The array has to be this way because at one point of the game I will have to compare and match element by element to see if you match the combo to decide if you win.

Should I convert it to `List<string>` or to `ArrayList`?

Comment: There is no sensible reason to choose `ArrayList` over `List<String>` unless it is an absolute requirement. Go with the generic version.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Can you elaborate more? I am rather new in C# and it is very different from JS and even OBJ-C.

Comment: You can find a lot of information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309694/arraylist-vs-list-in-c-sharp).

Comment: Note that title talks about multidimensional *array*, but post asks about using simple `List<string>` - please check what you actually want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

// Two-dimensional array.

```
int[,] array2D = new int[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } };
```

// The same array with dimensions specified.

```
int[,] array2Da = new int[4, 2] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } };
```

// A similar array with string elements.

```
string[,] array2Db = new string[3, 2] { { "one", "two" }, { "three", "four" },
                                    { "five", "six" } };
```

// Three-dimensional array.

```
int[, ,] array3D = new int[,,] { { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } }, 
                              { { 7, 8, 9 }, { 10, 11, 12 } } };
```

// The same array with dimensions specified.

```
int[, ,] array3Da = new int[2, 2, 3] { { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } }, 
                                   { { 7, 8, 9 }, { 10, 11, 12 } } };
```

Comment: +1. As it shows "arrays" as asked in title, but may not what OP needs due to "should I use `List<string>`" in the post...

Comment: @Lightwalker this seems like what I want. Let me verify it first and feedback to your answer later.

Comment: @Lightwalker What is the different of `int[,]` and `int[][]`?

Comment: @sooon i don't want to induce you to an error since i can't find nothing explaining this on google. 
For example string[,] array2Db = new string[3, 2]
the "[,]" is indicating it only has one separator(two dimensional array "[,]", meaning two columns).
so if you increase to  "new string[3, 2, 1]" you would need two separators "[,,]" (three dimensional array "[,,]", meaning three columns).