# C# - Dynamic Controls (combobox + label)

Tags: c#, windows

I make a code that aims to make a combobox with an associated label. How can I get the label to show the value found in the combo box.

There is provided a combobox and a label each time you press a button, so there will be x-number of comboboxes and labels.

```
ArrayList cboRunList = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList labRunList = new ArrayList();
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Tilføjer ComboBoxe
        ComboBox cboRun = new ComboBox();
        string[] s = { "", "a", "b", "c", "d", "1", "2", "3", "4" };
        cboRun.DataSource = s;
        cboRun.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 10 + (20 * c));
        cboRun.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 25);
        cboRunList.Add(cboRun);
        cboRun.Click += new EventHandler(cboRun_Click);
        Controls.Add(cboRun);


        // Tilføjer label
        Label labRun = new Label();
        labRun.Name = "LabDyn" + c;
        labRun.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(270, 10 + (20 * c));
        labRun.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1000, 20);
        labRunList.Add(labRun);
        labRun.Text = "LabDyn" + c;
        Controls.Add(labRun);
        c = c + 1;
```

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post [a minimal example of what needs to change](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and fully explain what needs to be modifed.

Comment: You need to create a `UserControl`.

Comment: in order to get code, one must first give code.

Comment: @CalvinSmith sorry, now the code is there.

Comment: @gunr2171 sorry, now the code is there.

Comment: Whoever gives an answer, please include the line "stop using ArrayLists", please.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I'd say your comment should be the answer.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Yes, converted to answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want some controls to be associated and work together, You need to create a [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx). Which is why they are for.

- Create a user control
- Add Combobox and Label
- Set the required properties,
- Wire the events and add your associated code to reflect one's change in another.

You're done with creating a UserControl. Now wherever you need this ComboBox and Label together, you'll create a instance of `YourNewUserControl` and add it to the parent(typically a `Form`).

Also give importance to [gunr2171](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1043380/gunr2171)'s comment. [Don't use ArrayList use `List<T>` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309694/arraylist-vs-list-in-c-sharp) for obvious reasons.

Comment: Good answer, and might i suggest the parent be a flow layout panel, because it makes it so much easier to just add the controls and not worry about where you are adding them.