# assign data from LINQ to ArrayList

Tags: c#, linq

Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType0`7[System.Int32,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Int32]' to type 'myWebApplication.tblmyWebsite

I'm very newbie to c#
Could anyone here tell me what's the problem in this code please?

AnonymousType0 when I need to get records from LINQ to SQL and show it to the browser using ArrayList.

see code please

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections; // so you can use ArrayList.
    using System.Text; // so you can use StringBuilder.
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace myWebApplication
{
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            showProducts();
        }
        private void showProducts()
        {
            dbDataContext db = new dbDataContext();

            var products = from p in db.tblmyWebsites
                           select p ;
            GridView1.DataSource = products;
            GridView1.DataBind();

            // the way to convert LINQ query to ArrayList
            ArrayList myArrList = new ArrayList();
            myArrList.AddRange((from p in db.tblmyWebsites
                                select new
                                {
                                    p.Id,
                                    p.productName,
                                    p.tblprogrammingLanguage.programmingLanguage, 
                                    p.tblapplicationType.applicationType,
                                    p.image,
                                    p.review, 
                                    p.price}).ToList());

            // StringBuilder Represents a mutable string of characters.
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (tblmyWebsite myProduct in myArrList)
            {
                sb.Append(string.Format(@"<table class = 'coffeeTable'>


                       <tr>
                           <th>Id: </th>
                           <td>{1}</td>
                       </tr>

                       <tr>
                           <th>productName: </th>
                           <td>{2}</td>
                       </tr>

                       <tr>
                           <th>programmingLanguage: </th>
                           <td>{3}</td>
                       </tr>

                       <tr>
                           <th>type: </th>
                           <td>{4}</td>
                       </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <th>image: </th>
                           <td>{5}</td>
                       </tr>

                       <tr>
                           <th>review: </th>
                           <td>{6}</td>
                       </tr>

                       <tr>
                           <th>price: </th>
                           <td>{7}</td>
                       </tr>
                       </table> ", myProduct.Id, myProduct.productName, myProduct.programmingLanguage, myProduct.type,
                                 myProduct.image, myProduct.review, myProduct.price).ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason to turn a LINQ enumeration into the non-generic `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are populating your array list with anonymous types here:

```
myArrList.AddRange((from p in db.tblmyWebsites
                            select new
                            {
                                p.Id,
                                p.productName,
                                p.tblprogrammingLanguage.programmingLanguage, 
                                p.tblapplicationType.applicationType,
                                p.image,
                                p.review, 
                                p.price}).ToList());
```

But then you try and do this:

```
foreach (tblmyWebsite myProduct in myArrList)
```

Your array list doesn't contain `tblmyWebsite` objects, it contains anonymous types. Even if they have the same fields with the same names, it won't convert them for you automatically. My assumption is that you `tblmyWebsite` is what you get from your database (in other words, db.tblmyWebsites is a collection of `tblmyWebsite` objects). So what you can do is simply:

```
myArrList.AddRange(db.tblmyWebsites);    // your array list is now populated with 
                                         // tblmyWebsite objects
```

There is no need to use `select` unless you actually need to change or remap something. There's also no real point in using `ArrayList`, generic `List<T>` is much easier to use. You could, in fact, just do:

```
 foreach (var myProduct in db.tblmyWebsites)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for the `ArrayList`.  Just use the query in your `foreach`.

```
var stuff = from p in db.tblmyWebsites
            select new
            {
                p.Id,
                p.productName,
                p.tblprogrammingLanguage.programmingLanguage, 
                p.tblapplicationType.applicationType,
                p.image,
                p.review, 
                p.price
            };
```

And

```
foreach(var myProduct in stuff)
```

The problem is that you are trying to cast an anonymous type (created by the `select new`) to a `tblmyWebsite` in your `foreach`.  When using anonymous types `var` is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

The [`ArrayList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx) data structure is a non-generic list. It was introduced prior to the concept of generics, and it offers no benefits over the generic [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx), except to support assemblies targetting the lower versions of the framework (compatability): https://stackoverflow.com/a/2309699/347172

---

That being said, you don't need to create a list from your enumeration if all you are simply using it in a **foreach** statement. Foreach works off of the `IEnumerable`/`IEnumerable<T>` interfaces, which is what your LINQ statement returns (an `IEnumerable<T>`).

```
foreach (var variable in LINQ-statement)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help 
And I think I need to spend some time to understand the technique behind .
Because the example was using connection string and class of the database, but I try to do the same sample with linq

Comment: I'll try to see the other solutions and verify it, and thank for all those who try to help