# How to get all values from database for a particular column

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I have a company table and i used query `select * from company` .But now i only require all the company name from this table , how toget and store in to a string array.Following code snippet only one i raw of company name i get. but how to get all company names and store in to an array

```
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            // write each record
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", 
                    reader["CompanyName"]; 

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1: Using an ArrayList**

> [ArrayList](http://www.dotnetperls.com/arraylist) dynamically resizes. As elements are added,and space is
>   needed, it grows in capacity. It is most often used in older C#
>   programs.

```
ArrayList companylist = new ArrayList();

reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

// write each record
while(reader.Read())
 {
    companylist.Add(reader["CompanyName"]);
 }

foreach (var name in companylist)
{ 
   Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

**Option 2: Using a List**

> [Replacement for deprecated ArrayList.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309694/arraylist-vs-list-in-c-sharp)

```
List<string> companylist = new List<string>();

reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

// write each record
while(reader.Read())
 {
    companylist.Add(reader["CompanyName"]);
 }

foreach (var name in companylist)
{ 
   Console.WriteLine(name);
}

//Converting list to string Array
var CompanyNamesArray = companylist.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you need it in an array specifically, or just a collection... but you could do the following:

```
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

List<string> listOfCompanyNames = new List<string>();

        // write each record
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", 
                reader["CompanyName"]; 
            listOfCompanyNames.Add(reader["CompanyName"]);
        }

        var arrayOfCompanyNames = listOfCompanyNames.ToArray();
```

Note you'll need to import `System.Collections.Generic` and `System.Linq`