# Using ArrayList at universal app

Tags: c#, arraylist, win-universal-app

Actually I'm using this code at universal app on the shared section

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;

namespace Tablaturas
{
    public class SeparadorDeSilabas
    {

        ArrayList posiciones; // Posiciones de inicio de las silabas
        String ultPal;        // Última palabra tratada, se guarda para
                              // no repetir el proceso si se pide la misma
    }
}
```

Now my problem is that **ArrayList** type resides at **System.Collections** But the compiler doesn't recognize it.

How can I do to use ArrayList at universal app? **or**

There is another equivalent type for universal app?

Comment: `List<T>` is preferred in .net 2.0 and newer.

Comment: It's 2015.. Please stop using `ArrayList` as there are much better generic equivalent - `List<T>` for some time...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Tks for the suggestion. This is an inherited code that i'm trying to port to vs 2013

Comment: I thought of losing this one as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309694/arraylist-vs-list-in-c-sharp, but it is really not duplicate...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There hasn't been a good reason to use `ArrayList` in new code for the last 9 years, but it's still around for backwards compatibility. With UWP they've taken the opportunity to purge the old legacy.

You can always replace an `ArrayList` with a `List<object>`. You can almost always do better to replace it with a `List<T>` for a more specific type unless you've a heterogeneous collection (one that contains items of lots of different types). Being more specific will generally give you code that is safer, faster (removing some unnecessary casting) and will possibly find some bugs in the original that you can then fix.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you should replace ArrayList to List. Check this link:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/469bb6cf-662e-43d6-84ae-119784bd9c9a/how-to-use-arraylist-class-in-metro-style-class-library-project?forum=winappswithcsharp