# C#: ArrayList.Clear() clears the wrong array

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist

I'm using ArrayList in C# to do some things.
I have 2 ArrayLists (align and best) and, in a specific time, I make best=align inside a "for" routine.

The problem is, in the end of the loop, I do align.Clear, but in this time, the array "best" gets cleared too. After the loop, when I have to use the array "best", I get troubles, because it is cleared and I try to access its index.

What's the problem?

Here is a piece of my code:

```
public string AntColony()
{
   ArrayList align = new ArrayList();
   ArrayList best = new ArrayList();

   for(int z=0;z<n_ants;z++)
   {
      //do the things i have to do
      //full the array "align" with something (this will have two "adds", so, this array is a 2 lines array)

      score = Score(align);
      UpdatePhero(tao, path, score);

      if (score > score_before)
      {
         score_before = score;
         best = align;
      }
      align.Clear(); //clear the array align
   }
   string s = best[0].ToString() + "\r\n\r\n" + best[1].ToString() + "\r\n\r\n Number of matches: " + n_matches + "\r\n\r\n Score: " + score;

   return s;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You are making `best` reference to point to `align`. C# is based on references!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And what I can do to solve this? I mean, what strategy? Anyway, I have to make best=align and clear the align array in the end.

Comment: Your query has already been solved by an author in the Answer section. Good Luck.

Comment: Also check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309694/arraylist-vs-list-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array variables are reference types.  When you call `best=align` you are not *copying* the contents of `align` to `array`, you are making it so that they point to the same place, i.e. they reference the same memory location.

Try `best=align.Clone()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I tried to do best=align.Clone(), but I got something like it is not possible to convert 'object' to 'Convert.Collections.ArrayList'.

Comment: It worked doing best = (ArrayList)align.Clone()
Thank you very much

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Since align is temporary, it can be recreated just before the call to `Score` and assigned to best when needed:

```
public string AntColony()
{
    ArrayList best = null;

    for(int z=0;z<n_ants;z++)
    {
      //do the things i have to do
      //full the array "align" with something (this will have two "adds", so, this array is a 2 lines array)

      ArrayList align = new ArrayList();
      score = Score(align);
      UpdatePhero(tao, path, score);

      if (score > score_before)
      {
         score_before = score;
         best = align;
      }
    }

    if (best != null)
    {
        string s = best[0].ToString() + "\r\n\r\n" + best[1].ToString() + "\r\n\r\n Number of matches: " + n_matches + "\r\n\r\n Score: " + score;
        return s;
    }

    // TODO: Report failure here

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Unfortunatelly I need the array align before the loop to do some other things!