# C# How to trigger an event when a static Arraylist count is changed?

Tags: c#, winforms, arraylist

I have a static array list in class called cart, is there a way to implement event listener to be used by other classes?
I am new to c# tried to understand PropertyChangedEventHandler with no success.
The arraylist and property are initialized as below:

```
private static ArrayList cartList = new ArrayList();

    public static ArrayList CartList
    {
        get { return cartList; }
        set
        {
            cartList = value;
        }
    }
```

Edit:

Altered @KMC code to work with List by hiding base methods:

```
public class ListOfProducts : List<Product>
{

    public void Add(Product obj)
    {
        base.Add(obj);
        this.OnChange();
    }

    public void UpdateLast(Product obj)
    {
        base[base.Count - 1] = obj;
        this.OnChange();
    }
    public void Remove(Product obj)
    {
        base.Remove(obj);
        this.OnChange();
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        base.Clear();
        this.OnChange();
    }

    public event EventHandler Change;

    protected void OnChange()
    {
        if (this.Change != null)
        {
            this.Change(this, new EventArgs() { });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could implement INotifyProperty changed. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315621/implementing-inotifypropertychanged-does-a-better-way-exist

Comment: Could you be more specific? Do you want to receive events related to ArrayList itself or to each item contained in the list?

Comment: As a side note: Refrain from using ArrayList. Use List<Cart> instead. Why? Because ArrayList is the old non-generic way of lists and stores all items as 'object'. List<Cart> will store all items as a Cart object instead so you don't need to cast. Both more convenient and better performance.

Comment: @rudolf_franek I want to recieve events for the change in number of of the contained items in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the ArrayList type is extensible. you can override the add and remove methods and fire some events.

for ex)

```
public class NewArrayList : ArrayList 
{
    public event EventHandler Change; 

    public override int Add(object value)
    { 
       var result = base.Add(value);
        this.OnChange();
        return result;
    }

    public override void Remove(object obj)
    {
        base.Remove(obj);
        this.OnChange();
    }

    protected void OnChange()
    {
        if (this.Change != null)
        {
            this.Change(this, new EventArgs() { });
        }
    }
}
public static class program
{ 
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var list = new NewArrayList();
        list.Change += delegate (object sender, EventArgs arg) {
            Console.WriteLine("collect changed {0}", list.Count);
        };

        list.Add(1);
        list.Add(2);
        list.Remove(2);

    }  

}
```

since the ArrayList needs to send some type of message (event) and I'm not sure who will be receiving it, I'll leave it up to you.

Comment: I really wouldn't recommend using ArrayList in this age though. At least, not in new code that others are going to use.

Comment: I will switch to List<object> but this is the logic I was searching for thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get notified when count of elements in `ArrayList` changes nor when any element changes.

`ArrayList` and most other standard collections in .Net Framework like `List<T>`, `Dictionary` and arrays (except specialized classes like [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) in WPF) do not provide notification on items added/removed. You can easily check that by looking at MSDN entry for corresponding class and see if it implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` and/or `INotifyPropertyChanged`. I.e. [ArrayList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx) only implements `IList, ICollection, IEnumerable, ICloneable` and no notification interfaces.

If you need notification of such change you should create your own class with such notification or use `ObservableCollection`.

Side note: please consider using `List<T>` instead of non-generic `ArrayList`- [ArrayList vs List<> in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309694/arraylist-vs-list-in-c-sharp).