# Count not adding for each item, adding as a total C# console application

Tags: c#, console-application

trying to get a count of each item in the array, however its adding a total number.

```
  Dictionary<string, int> counts = new Dictionary<string, int>() {
          { "HelloWorld", 0},
          { "Hello", 0},
          { "World", 0},
          { "integer", 0},
        };


        foreach (var item in arraylist)
        {
            counts["HelloWorld"] += 1;
            counts["Hello"] += 1;
            counts["World"] += 1;
            counts["integer"] += 1;

        }

        Console.WriteLine("");

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> item in counts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Key.ToString() + ":" + item.Value.ToString());
        }


        Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

E.g. Input: 1,10

Expected output:

```
hello: 3
world: 5
helloworld: 1
integer: 11
```

Run below dotnet fiddle to find issue:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/eKHb5x

Comment: Please post your code in your question. A fiddle is great, but we need to see the relevant code (and no more, preferably) in the actual question.

Comment: Sorry, code added

Comment: You are incrementing the counts for everything in your foreach loop against arraylist.

Comment: How do I do it per item?

Comment: answered below. Heres the fiddle:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/HescNb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use if statements inside your foreach loop i.e.

```
foreach (var item in arraylist)
{
    if (item.Equals("Hello") )
    {
        counts["Hello"]++;
    }
    else if (item.Equals("World"))
    {
        counts["World"]++;
    }
    else if (item.Equals("HelloWorld"))
    {
        counts["HelloWorld"]++;
    }
    else if (item.Equals("integer"))
    {
        counts["integer"]++;
    }
}
```

Also, just a nitpick, you don't need

```
item.Key.ToString()
```

since the key is a string to begin with

```
item.Key
```

should suffice.

Comment: .equals does not work. Object does not contain a definition for equals and no extension method

Comment: Sorry, .Equals with a capital E.

Comment: That would work, for everything except the integer. As the integer isint called integer, it will be 1,2,3

Comment: How do you search for integers in the array? rather than the string integer

Comment: Either use a bool from int.Tryparse(stringValue, out intPlaceholder) OR just turn the last else if into an else.

Answer (score 1):

Change your ArrayList to a `List<string>`.

When you iterate over it, use the item variable as the key to your dictionary.

```
        foreach(string item in list) {
            if(counts.ContainsKey(item)) {
                counts[item]++;
            } else {
                counts["integer"]++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What's the benefit of converting to List<string>?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309694/arraylist-vs-list-in-c-sharp

Comment: So instead of converting the entire collection, I could just swap your if for if d.ContainsKey(item.ToString())) for the same result?

Comment: Using a List<string> vs calling item.ToString() are not remotely the same thing. You will achieve similar but less performant code. Whereas I have a list of objects that are already strings and do not need to be converted to strings, you have a list of objects that need to be converted to strings every time you need to do an operation on them and all the operations you do are string operations.

Answer (score 0):

Change your array list to a List and do this

```
foreach(var item in arrayList)
{
    if(counts.Contains(item))
    {
        counts[item]++;
    }
    else if (int.TryParse(item, out var i)) // this is a newish feature and my syntax might be a bit off
    {
        counts["integer"]++;
    }
}
```

I did this on my phone so sorry if there are any spelling mistakes. I'll check back shortly and correct then on my laptop