# How to copy the entire column from Excel to array list in vb.net?

Tags: excel, vb.net

I want to copy the entire column from excel to array list to compare the data.

```
 Dim file_name As New ArrayList
        file_name.Add(xlworksheet1.Range("a1").EntireColumn)
        Console.WriteLine(file_name)
        For Each Name1 In file_name
            Console.WriteLine(Name1)
        Next
```

Comment: What problem are you having _specifically_ with the code you have supplied?

Answer (score 1):

This is my suggestion:

```
Dim file_name As New ArrayList
' find the last row with values
Dim Lr As Integer = xlworksheet1.Cells(xlworksheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row

' loop trough all cells in column 1 (A)
For i = 1 To Lr
    file_name.Add(xlworksheet1.Cells(i, 1).value)
Next

Console.WriteLine(file_name)
For Each Name1 In file_name
    Console.WriteLine(Name1)
Next
```

also consider using [`List(of T)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309694/arraylist-vs-list-in-c-sharp) instead of `ArrayList`.