# How to convert a HashSet to an ArrayList in PowerShell?

Tags: arrays, list, powershell, arraylist

I need to convert a HashSet to an ArrayList?

```
$hashset = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[int]
$hashset.Add(1)
$hashset.Add(2)
$hashset.Add(3)

$arraylist = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
# Now what?
```

Comment: did you try [array]$arraylist = $hashset .  both variables after this still pipe to "get-member" with the same output. What is your goal in creating an array vs a "hashset"

Comment: @RobertCotterman I need an ArrayList. Arrays are fixed size and don't have `Sort()`.

Comment: Daniel, arrays in Powershell can be sorted with Sort-Object and you can add items to them (it will create a new array to do that, but from a language standpoint it doesn't really matter what the type is -- unless, of course, you totally ed the ArrayList to pass to a method that requires one. But I hope such APIs are long dead now.)

Comment: @Joey I often prefer using ArrayList or List because the way PowerShell handles arrays, especially when adding new items, is *damn slow*.

Comment: @Joey The lists can become quite big and I don't want to copy big lists every time I add one item. Beside that, I also need `GetRange()` which also isn't supported by the Array that `Sort-Object` returns.

Comment: @marze: Indeed, with the added details using a list is preferable. I just tend to write PowerShell in a way that minimises mutation of collections and instead use the pipeline for such things as much as possible. It's not always possible or convenient, of course.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way, using `CopyTo`:

```
$array = New-Object int[] $hashset.Count
$hashset.CopyTo($array)
$arraylist = [System.Collections.ArrayList]$array
```

Another way (shorter, but slower for large hashsets):

```
$arraylist = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@($hashset)
```

Also, I **strongly** recommend to favor `List` over `ArrayList`, as it's pretty much [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2309699/2060966) since the introduction of generics:

```
$list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[int]]$hashset
```

Comment: Didn't know about lists. Thanks.

Comment: Nice, List[int]++. Worth noting that if you're using PowerShell >5.0, the constructor takes any `IEnumerable[int]` (including `HashSet[int]`) directly as its argument, faster than casting it: `[System.Collections.Generic.List[int]]::new($hashset)`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Did you actually try if it's faster? Because PowerShell's cast does use a constructor implicitly, if possible.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2013/06/11/understanding-powershells-type-conversion-magic/

Comment: @marsze yes, but due to `@()`, the set is expanded to an array first. If I pass it directly to the constructor, I have it return the new list in approx. 10ms, whereas if I do your cast, it gets slower the bigger the set gets :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I've already removed the `@()` in my answer, it's unnecessary, as you correctly stated. *Another* nice benefit of using `List` instead of `ArrayList`! Then you can just do the cast and it will be about the same speed is it's (most likely) using the constructor internally.

Comment: @marsze sorry, didn't see you'd updated the answer, looking sweet :-D

Answer (score 5):

Unsure if this is what you are after but it here you go...

```
$hashset = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[int]
$null = $hashset.Add(1)
$null = $hashset.Add(2)
$null = $hashset.Add(3)
# @($hashset) converts the hashset to an array which is then 
# converted to an arraylist and assigned to a variable
$ArrayList = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@($hashset)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also add every item from `hashtable` to `array` using `foreach` loop:

```
$hashset = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[int]
$hashset.Add(1)
$hashset.Add(2)
$hashset.Add(3)

$arraylist = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
# Now what?
foreach ($item in $hashset){
    $arraylist.Add($item)
}
```

Comment: You should use `$arraylist.Add($item) | Out-Null` or `[void]$arraylist.Add($item)` to prevent unwanted output to the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks. That's how I do it at the moment. But it's unnecessarily verbose for my taste.