# Which collection is useful in case of dotnet remoting and Serailization?

Tags: c#, collections, .net-remoting

I have used ArrayList and List as well and came to know that List is reference type so that we can not use this in case of **dotnet Remoting**.

As suggested in [ArrayList vs List<> in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309694/arraylist-vs-list-in-c-sharp) post that

```
ArrayList belongs to the days that C# didn't have generics. 
It's deprecated in favor of List<T>.

List<double> listCollection = new List<double>(); // Good in case of single machine project but not in case of dotnet remoting.
ArrayList list = new ArrayList(); // Can store multiple type of object.
```

So we should not use ArrayList.

Now considering Array, then Array creation must have Array size as

```
double[] abc = new double[];    // Not correct
double[] abc = new double[10];  // Correct.
```

I have also seen **MarshalByRefObject** as in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.marshalbyrefobject?view=netframework-4.7.2 but I do not want to use this.

So my question is that which is the best way to use a **collection of the same type** of class without using any of the above and which is most suitable for **.net remoting** and can be **Serializable**?

Comment: @JohnB yeah that's right, as per project, I have to use this old technology. This is not in my hand. Can you suggest any other technology?

Comment: is there anypoint suggesting if you have to used it?

Comment: @JohnB; Yes, of course, may be beneficial in other projects and I am eager to learn new technologies.

Comment: why not serialize the object then send it? Then you can reconstruct it on the remote side?

Comment: .NET Remoting was identified as a problematic architecture. It's used for cross-AppDomain communication, which is no longer supported. Also, Remoting requires runtime support, which is expensive to maintain. For these reasons, .NET Remoting isn't supported on .NET Core