# C# Using Stack with Exception

Tags: c#, stack

```
// Program (Main)
var s = new UniqueStack<int>();
            s.Push(3);
            s.Push(2);
            s.Push(1);
            s.Push(1);                    // Exception
            while (s.Count > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s.Pop());     // 1->2->3
            }
```

I want to bring this Code to life. I had a very similiar task once and tried to make it for this task works, but it didn't works well, because I have some parts of it as blanks, because i dont know how to go forward.

```
// UniqueStack (Class)
using System;
using System.Collections;

namespace StackTest
{
    internal class UniqueStack<T> : ICollection
    {

        private ArrayList<T> items = new ArrayList<T>();

        public int Count
        {
            get { return items.Count; }
        }
        public UniqueStack()
        {
        }

        public void Push(T item)
        {
            items.Add(item);

        }

        public T Pop()
        {
            T item;

            if (items.Count == 0)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("No items in stack");

            item = items[items.Count - 1];
            items.RemoveAt(items.Count - 1);

            return item;
        }
    }



}
```

I clearly see, that this Code didn't throw an exception, when its a clone of a existing pushed number.
And my ICollection don't work for this example, because the code doesn't work with it.
Any one who can help an very poor skilled programer?

Thank you!

```
internal class UniqueStack<T>
    {

        private List<T> items = new List<T>();

        public int Count
        {
            get { return items.Count; }
        }
        public UniqueStack()
        {
        }

        public void Push(T item)
        {
            if (items.Contains(item))
            {
            throw new System.InvalidOperationException("Doppelte Werte sind nicht erlaubt!");

            }
            items.Add(item);
        }

        public T Pop()
        {
            T item;

            if (items.Count == 0)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("No items in stack");

            item = items[items.Count - 1];
            items.RemoveAt(items.Count - 1);

            return item;
        }


        public override string ToString()
        {
            string s = "";



            while (items != null)
            {
                s += items.ToString() + " -> ";

            }
            s += "Count: " + Count.ToString();

            return s;
        }
    }
```

My code does work, but I can't display it right. 
It says
1
2
3

Instead of 1 - > 2 - > 3

Comment: Dont use `ArrayList`

Comment: There is no generic `ArrayList` in C#, so this code wouldn't even compile.

Comment: Why don't you use an actual stack as the underlying data structure?

Comment: Honestly if you change `ArrayList` to `List` and remove `: ICollection` this code will work just fine.

Comment: I did changed the Code above. Now it works fine and now duplicates are in my code.

last question: Any idea, why my toString doesn't work.
I want to display 1 -> 2 -> 3

Comment: Your `ToString` can be `return string.Join(" -> ", items);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ArrayList vs List<> in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309694/arraylist-vs-list-in-c-sharp)

Comment: No, I don't need to understand the difference between lists. But Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you want a Stack that does not allow duplicates then you can use a `Stack<T>` as the underlying type and a `HashSet<T>` to determine if the items you push already exist in the stack.  You can even include a constructor that take a `IEqualityComparer<T>` so that you can tell it how to determine if two items are equal.

```
public class UniqueStack<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>
{
    private readonly Stack<T> _stack = new Stack<T>();
    private readonly HashSet<T> _hash;

    public UniqueStack()
    {
        _hash = new HashSet<T>();
    }

    public UniqueStack(IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        _hash = new HashSet<T>(comparer);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _stack.Clear();
        _hash.Clear();
    }

    public T Peek() => _stack.Peek();

    public T Pop()
    {
        var item = _stack.Pop();
        _hash.Remove(item);
        return item;
    }

    public void Push(T item)
    {
        // HashSet.Add returns true if the item was not already in the set.
        if (_hash.Add(item))
        {
            _stack.Push(item);
        }
        else
        {
            // You can throw an exception on duplicate or ignore them.
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _stack.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public int Count => _stack.Count;

    // Here's a ToString override that does what you want
    public override string ToString() =>
        string.Join(" -> ", _stack);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, juharr. I know, that there is Stack from Microsoft itself, but I try to understand how it works. My last problem is just to print the items with -> between and side by side.

Comment: I've added a `ToString` override.  Note that if the stack is empty then it returns an empty string.

Comment: With my code your toString gives just out, what i've got before. 
1
2
3

and not 1 -> 2-> 3

Comment: I don't get, why my question is closed. @servy