# SqlDataReader to string[]

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

why the following code doesn't work?

```
internal static string[] GetToolsForRole(string selectedRole) {
  string[] tempStr;
  ArrayList myAL = new ArrayList();
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_TD_SelectByRoleName");
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

  cmd.Parameters.Add("@role", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = selectedRole;

  SqlConnection myConnection = Util.GetConnection();
  cmd.Connection = myConnection;
  SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

  int i = 0;
  while (reader.Read()) {
    tempStr[i] = reader["TD_Name"].ToString();
    i++;
  }

  return tempStr;
}
```

Comment: Just wondering, why not ArrayList?  Sure List<T> is strongly typed, but with just strings isn't ArrayList just fine?

Comment: @Hogan: Huh? How is ArrayList any better with strings?  You should _always_ use `List<T>`.

Comment: @SLaks : I would guess it was marginally faster unless it is implemented strangely.

Comment: @Hogan: An ArrayList will never be faster than a `List<T>`.  (I have no sources for that statement)

Comment: @Slaks : My understanding is parameterized types are instantiated at runtime -- this would have to require more overhead in time and memory than pre-compiled code which just manages pointers.  Am I missing something?  (I will admit we are talking about relatively small differences).

Comment: @Slaks : Nevermind -- I'm wrong http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391088/arraylist-vs-listobject/391102#391102

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays don't work like that.

You should use a `List<string>`, and call the `Add` method.

To use an array,you need to create a new array by writing `tempStr = new string[size]`.  Arrays cannot be resized in-place.

Comment: i changed to List<string>, but still get  "Use of unassigned local variable 'tempStr'"

Comment: @eyalb: You need to put a `new List<string>` into your variable.

Answer (score 0):

You never allocate `tempStr`.

Try this in loop:

```
myAL.Add(reader["TD_Name"].ToString());
```

Then this at return

```
return (String[]) myAL.ToArray( typeof( string ) );
```

You won't need (remove) the `i` and `tempStr` variables.