# Nodelist to arraylist<String> conversion

Tags: java, xml

I have extracted nodelist like,
`this.NodeList xml = doc.getElementsByTagName(tagName)`

Now I want to convert the xml to ArrayList type, any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

**Concerning Java**

Since Java 8, you can work with IntStream and map, where nodeList is instance of `NodeList` :

```
List<String> nodeNames = IntStream.range(0, nodeList.getLength())
        .mapToObj(nodeList::item)
        .map(n -> n.getNodeName())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will collect the nodes' name into a list.

For more general purpose, you can collect the `Node` elements and then work on it:

```
List<Node> nodes = IntStream.range(0, nodeList.getLength())
        .mapToObj(nodeList::item)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that since Java 10, you could also just `var` instead of `List<Node>`:

```
var nodes = IntStream.range(0, nodeList.getLength())
        .mapToObj(nodeList::item)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var nodeArrayList = new ArrayList(xmlNodeList.OfType<XmlNode>().ToList());
```

Comment: Assuming it's C#, there's no good reason to use `ArrayList` over `List<XmlNode>`.

Comment: @DBM: Agreed, but he might be just looking to pass the right arguments to some existing method beyond his control. Question doesn't say much.

Comment: Although `ArrayList` is an implementation of `List<something>` there's no much advantage. Interesting answer related to this at http://stackoverflow.com/a/391257/448232.