# Convert NodeList to List in Java

Tags: java, xml

I need to convert a NodeList to List in order to return an iterator over the List.

My requirement is to return NodeSetData objects, the iterator method MUST return an iteration over objects of type org.w3c.dom.Node.

I have a NodeList containing a list of all of my Nodes that are required to be returned. In order to return an Iterator, I need to convert NodeList to List.

I have looked through a bunch of stackoverflow answer but most of them relates to conversion of NodeList to String.

Here is the function that is going to be used to return iterator.

```
return new NodeSetData() {

             public Iterator iterator() {

                 return l.iterator();
             };
         };
```

Any leads regarding how to convert NodeList to List will really help.

Comment: All you need is a good old for loop

Comment: Looking at the documentations a NodeList has exactly two methods. What a coincidence that they are exactly the two you need. [Have a look at the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html) and I am sure you will find a good solution.

Comment: If you don't want a typed iterator, you could use `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.util.xml.NodeListIterator`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just implement via anonymous classes.

```
return new NodeSetData() {
    @Override
    public Iterator iterator() {
        return new Iterator() {
            private int i = 0;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return nodeList.getLength() < i;
            }

            @Override
            public Node next() {
                return nodeList.item(i++);
            }
        };
    }
};
```

Comment: you need to increment `i`

Answer (score 4):

Found this answer provided by [KeyMaker00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1039203/keymaker00) while searching for the same.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50169546/19376122

He used IntStream and map function to iterate through the NodeList and map it to a List;

```
List<Node> nodes = IntStream.range(0, nodeList.getLength())
    .mapToObj(nodeList::item)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

As this may be useful for others, here is a simple function doing it:

```
  public static List<Element> getElements(final NodeList nodeList) {
    final int len = nodeList.getLength();
    final List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<>(len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      final Node node = nodeList.item(i);
      if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        elements.add((Element) node);
      }
      // Ignore other node types.
    }
    return elements;
  }
```