# How to create an event (Canvas move) C# WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, kinect

in my app, a canvas moves when i move my handRigth (kinect SDK), I need to create a method (C#, Wpf)that allows me to store the coordinates of Y (arrayList of 100 positions). this method content:

```
alLastCoor_HandRight.Add(dYpuntero); //ArrayList, dYpuntero=Position
if (alLastCoor_HandRight.Count > 100)// Limit ArrayList 100 positions
alLastCoor_HandRight.RemoveAt(0);
```

and each time enter the method, store 100 positions of Y canvas position.
How can i do that ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, never use `ArrayLists` as they do the same thing as `Lists` only less efficiently (see [ArrayList vs List<object>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391088/arraylist-vs-listobject)). The way I would do this is by having a `Boolean` to decide if the count was greater than 100 or less than 100 like this:

```
    private bool HasLessThan100(List<double> list)
    {
        if (list.Count <= 100) return true;

        if (list.Count > 100) return false;

        return false;
    }
```

Then for your method, call it like this:

```
    private void MoveCanvas(List<double> list, double dYpuntero)
    {
        if (HasLessThan100(list))
        {
            list.Add((double)dYpuntero);
        }

        else return;
    }
```

Comment: its not exactly what i ask, (create a method CanvasMove), but it helps me to optimize my arrangement of coordinates. thnks so much!.

Comment: can u help me ? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194730/how-do-compare-a-exactly-position-of-mediaelement-while-playing)

Comment: @Makito if it helped you, accept as answer... Regarding your other question, Tim has the right approach

Comment: ....i see, but i dont understand how to use the clock property to resolve my question (link)... :/ i´m sorry this is new for me (clock property to mediaelement and This forum StackOverFlow.

Comment: @Makito I don't deal with that sort of mediaelements from little to none, I would wait for Tim to explain it better