# why microsoft allowed list<object> = new list<object>() feature from 2.0?

Tags: c#, generics

I have been learning collection and generics and understood that generics were introduced to 
provide more type safe containers and to improve the application performance by reducing number of boxing/unboxing.

But, If that was the case, why does the framework allows to create generics collection of type system.objects which can take any other type?

```
List<object> listObj = new List<object>();

listObj.Add(new Program1());
listObj.Add(new Program2());
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391088/arraylist-vs-listobject

Comment: Questions about "why microsoft x" are usually best answered by Microsoft. :)

Comment: Would you prefer you be forced to use `ArrayList` when you want a `List<object>`, but use `List<T>` for any other `T`?  Surely consistency is better.  That's kind of the point of Generics.  A `List<object>` can be used like a `List<string>` can be used like a `List<int>`.

Comment: The point of generics is to *enable* type safe containers if you want them, not to *prevent you from a loosely typed container* if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a list of things that are neither the same type, nor share a base class, nor share an interface, then you need `List<Object>`.

You very rarely need this.

But if you pursue the thought that `List<Object>` should be disallowed because it encourages unnecessary and dangerous downcasts, and anyway with generics you can just specify the types actually can handle, shouldn't you then go all the way and disallow the use of `Object` entirely?

Comment: A list of any non-sealed class can contain items that are not the same type.  A list that can contain (almost) *any* type needs to be a `List<object>`.  That's different.

Comment: Yeah as @Servy pointed, out I can easily apply polymorphism to get a collection of many different types. Take for example a `List<Car>` could hold objects of type `Chevy` and `Ford` which inherit from the `Car` class. When using `List<object>` you're applying the exact same mechanism only it is at the root of the inheritance hierarchy.

Answer (score 3):

Yes the collection is `List<T>` is `object` not a type? `object` is a type like any other (being the base type doesn't make it any different) and therefor can be used as the type argument for generic collections, there is nothing wrong with that, just don't do it when you know what the specific type is.

Answer (score 2):

I would say: why not. A list of objects, in which form you want it is totally legit. I personally don't want the framework to tell me what to do. It is fine to do suggestions, but prevent this code? No.