# Binding to ArrayList and Getting SelectedItem

Tags: c#, xaml

Hello So I have a ArrayList called AllQueries, And it's very dynamic. The Columns changes on what interactions are made to the UI. But the first column is always the ID column. So for example it can show ID, Name, Birthday where as another instance it'll show ID, Date, Subject.

```
private ArrayList _AllQueries { get; set; }
public ArrayList AllQueries { get { return _AllQueries; } set { _AllQueries = value; this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => AllQueries); } }
```

xaml code:

```
<telerik:RadGridView SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem2}" ItemsSource="{Binding AllQueries, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
```

I'm trying to grab the value of the row but I am having trouble and it's not giving me the row value.

```
public ArrayList SelectedItem2 { get; set; }
```

When I put a breakpoint where SelectedItem2 is being used, the `Count` is zero and i believe that means no value is being brought through.

```
using (var ctx = DB.Get()) i = ctx.Interactions.Find(SelectedItem2.IndexOf(0));
```

Comment: Any specific reason for using `ArrayList` and not `List<T>` ?

Comment: Because I dont have a T value, the query changes and is very ambiguous so it's not a static value. And columns change quite frequently

Comment: Unless I'm thinking about it wrong, but that's my interpretation of why im using arraylist

Comment: Not really sure about your scenario but still you can use `List<object>` See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391088/arraylist-vs-listobject

Comment: Would my SelectItem2 be `public Object SelectedItem2 after?`