# How to create a list that contains a list of different types

Tags: c#

Let's say I have such lists :

```
var firstList = new List<ofsometype>();
var secondList = new List<ofsomeanothertype>();
var thirdList = new List<anothertype>();
```

How can I make a list that accepts those lists? Like

```
var mainList = new List<???>();
mainList.Add(firstlist);
mainList.Add(secondlist);
mainList.Add(thirdlist);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use `List<object>` - but then you'll be into the realms of cast-o-rama...

Comment: Well, unless they implement something common you can only use `List<object>`. `List<T>` implements some non-generic interfaces as well but without knowing what you intend to use the list for and how you intend to use it that way, it is impossible to give you a more specific advice.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Actually I'm generating many lists of many types, then I'm joining them. That's all.

Comment: you can also try `var mainList = new List<IList>();`

Comment: If the types are yours you can add a nice Interface to them, best one that provides useful services beyobf being listable..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd probably use a Dictionary collection instead :

```
var firstList = new List<ofsometype>();
var secondList = new List<ofsomeanothertype>();
var thirdlist = new List<anothertype>();

var listsDict = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
listsDict.Add(typeof(ofsometype), firstlist);
listsDict.Add(typeof(ofsomeanothertype), secondlist);
listsDict.Add(typeof(anothertype), thirdlist);
```

The advantage here is that it gives you the information regarding the type of a list. This could be used for two things :

1. Filter list for a certain type only
2. Know the type for`List<object>` later by simply using the key

P.S.

Depending on what the solution is and what you'd need to achieve you can use generics (if type is known) or `dynamic`s - if type is unknown, but still a dynamic operation at run-time is required if compiler doesn't know the type.

Comment: I much prefer this answer to the list of IList one, it reads much more clearly and prevents a lot of the casting issues with the other solution

Comment: Can you give an example to converting please?

Comment: @Dillanm Why does this prevent casting issues? You still have to cast the list, where using a list-of-objects you would have to cast the object. I can't see why this is the better solution.

Comment: @Maarten Sorry, it maybe doesn't prevent casting issues per sé but it at least gives you a helping hand to tell you what to cast the object to based on the key of the dictionary, the list approach doesn't have this advantage.

Comment: @Dillanm tbh this could be done using reflection, but it could have performance impact and it's much easier to use the Key instead.

Comment: @ВиталийТерзиев  ArrayList is obsolete and it seem that no one use it these days. Marc Gravell explains why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391088/arraylist-vs-listobject

Comment: yep, thanks for the info link, i guess these days its all about generics and non-legacy code which kinda makes sense (if you are not writing your solo project) :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add items from lists of different types, then they need to share either a common base class, or inherit from the same interface, e.g.

```
ofsometype : ISomeInterface
ofsomeanothertype: ISomeInterface
anothertype: ISomeInterface

var firstList = new List<ofsometype>();
var secondList = new List<ofsomeanothertype>();
var secondList = new List<anothertype>();

var mainList = new List<ISomeInterface>();
mainList.AddRange(firstlist);
mainList.AddRange(secondlist);
mainList.AddRange(thirdlist);
```

You'll be limited to accessing the members exposed by ISomeInterface when retrieving items from the list, unless you resort to casting/reflection.

This can also be achieved by adding them to a `List<object>`, but that gives you next to no information about what's contained in the list.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If I use `List<object>`, will I be able to iterate the main list and get the members(the lists of different types).

Comment: @jason did you consider the option of using a Dictionary where the key would be the type and the value a IList object? It would make casting a bit easier when retrieving the list - although it would work only if there can be at most one list with a certain type.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use Object.

`List<Object>` or `Object[]` for array

```cs
var mainList = new List<List<Object>>();
mainList.Add(firstlist);
mainList.Add(secondlist);
mainList.Add(thirdlist);
```

I suggest this

```cs
var mainList = new List<Object[]>();
mainList.Add(firstlist.toArray());
mainList.Add(secondlist.toArray());
mainList.Add(thirdlist.toArray());
```