# Is there a way to print csv file data to console if the data matches another csv file?

Tags: c#, csv, readline

I want to be able to check one csv file with another csv file. If the first column of data in file1 matches the first column of data in file2 only print the rows that match and not the rest of them. I know how to print a csv file to the console but was wondering if there's a way to do this.. There is code below of what i have done so far but i don't think it is the right way to go about it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
operands = new ArrayList();

string[] file1 = file.ReadAllLines(@"..\..\data1.csv").Split(',');
string[] file2 = file.ReadAllLines(@"..\..\data2.csv").Split(',');

foreach (var line in file1)
{
 if (line.Split(',')[0].Equals(file2[0])
 {
   operands.AddRange(file1);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check first column of each line of `file1` with *each line of `file2`*,

you can try below

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collection.Generic;
...

//ReadAllLines() returns string[], you can't split string array, you need split individual element
string[] file1 = file.ReadAllLines(@"..\..\data1.csv");
string[] file2 = file.ReadAllLines(@"..\..\data2.csv");
List<string> operands = new List<string>();
for(int i = 0; i < Math.Min(file1.Length, file2.Length); i ++)
{
    if(file1[i].Split(',').First().Equals(file2[i].Split(',').First()))
    {                                  //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ This was missing 
        Console.WriteLine($"Line {i+1} matches first column data");
        operands.Add(file1[i]);

        //If you want to use ArrayList, then
        //operands.Add(file1[i]); //You were missing index i.e [i]
    } 
}
```

From your updated code, I would suggest use [`List<string>` instead of `ArrayList`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/391257/6299857) and store  entire row to it.

Comment: If the original file was being stored in an array list is it possible to create a new ArrayList with this new file where they equal each other?

Comment: If it is a CSV file, then file will be stored in comma separated values. I did not understand what is logic behind array list. Can you please elaborate and if this is related to the question which you asked then update your original question