# C# - how to create a list that can contain one of three different types of models

Tags: c#

I have a project with a list that can be `List<Fuel>`, `List<Trip>`, or `List<Purchase>`. The models are very similar; the key difference is in how they are processed. Is there a way I can create one list object that can contain all three and be able to send the types to the right methods?

Comment: You could just have a `List<object>`, or if they share a common base class or interface then you can have a `List<BaseClass>` or `List<IBaseInterface>`.  Why do you want to have one list contain all of these seemingly unrelated objects in the first place? Sounds like your design itself might not be a good idea.

Comment: The _FP_ solution is to use a tagged-union (first, get https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf ) then decide if you want `List<OneOf<Fuel,Trip,Purchase>>` or `OneOf<List<Fuel>,List<Trip>,List<Purchase>>`.

Comment: @mason when you said List<object> it effectively accounts to when someone ask you how to distinguish between Pomerol and St Emillion you say - drink beer ;)

Comment: Apart from a `List<object>` you might as well use a non-generic list type, even if it is out of fashion - such as an `ArrayList`.
To dispatch the items to the right method, you just need to check their type using `is`. Pattern matching or new variants of the switch statement come into play...

Comment: Create a base class with common properties.  Then each class (Fuel, Trip, Purchase) would inherit the base class and contain properties not in the common class.

Comment: @lidqy Strongly disagree. There is no legitimate use for `ArrayList` in .NET programs _at all_. Use `List<Object>` instead (the `ArrayList` type really should be marked with `[Obsolete]` at this point).

Comment: @Dai Isn't a `List<Object>` kind of absurdity? A generically strong typed list where the type parameter is completely pointless and unused? You just might leave out the type parameter. Which resolves to an `ArrayList`.

Comment: @lidqy `ArrayList` does not implement `IEnumerable<Object>`, `IList<T>` nor `IReadOnlyList<T>` which means you can't use it with Linq or take advatange of reference-type covariance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391088/arraylist-vs-listobject

Comment: In order to properly do Linq, you need to cast the item in your lambda anyhow. Since they're typed as `object` you won't get any further than 'Equals' and 'GetHashCode' else wise. So not actually a gain, isn't it?
Since the OP stated all he wants is a container for a bunch of mixed objects and iterate them to invoke some function, an ArrayList actually is suitable. Personally, I never use ArrayLists. I use List<object> as well, but always thinking that a List<object> is a dumb thing. Most often points out some misconception.

Comment: @lidqy Linq's extension methods are defined only for `IEnumerable<T>` (including `IEnumerable<Object>`) but not `IEnumerable` - so if you use `ArrayList`  you will _always_ need to add an ugly `.Cast<Object>()` step which is unnecessary with `List<Object>`. Additionally, with `List<T>` you can specify `List<Object?>` or `List<Object>`: you can't do that with `ArrayList`.

Comment: _"an ArrayList actually is suitable"_ - it's only "suitable" if you're okay with throwing type-safety out of the window.

Comment: @Dai you didn't get the point. Having an IEnumerable<T> makes your collection linq-able, true. But when you T is object, there is almost nothing you can do with it xcept callign Equals and GetHashCode...
So this is just an pseudo-benefit. (And also a waste of time arguing on it)

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways you can achieve that:

#### OPTION 1: `List<object>`

The easies one is `List<object>` and switch the type. IN c# you can do this:

```cs
var mylist = new List<object>(){ new Fuel(), new Trip(), new Purchase() };
foreach (var item in mylist)
{
  switch (item)
  {
    case Fuel item_as_fuel:
      item_as_fuel.Refuel(6);
      break;
    case Trip item_as_trip:
      item_as_trip.ToCity("Berlin");
      break;
    case Purchase pp:
      pp.SendPayment();
      break;
    default:
      throw new IvalidOperationException("invalid type");
  }
}
```

#### OPTION 2: interface

Another easy option is to implement an Interface
Contrary to the abstract class in the previus answer, the interface will not beak your inherithance and will allow for easy expansion.

```cs
interface ISomeMeaningfulNameThatCorrelatesTheThreeClasses
{
  void PerformOrAnotherMeaningfulNameForYourSpecificCase(params object[] args);
}
// i will now call it IBase to simplify but you get the idea
class Fuel : IBase
{
  // i strongly suggest explicit implementations 
  // because it will only apply when used as interface
  void IBase.Perform(params object[] args)
  {
    //custom implementation
    this.Refuel((int)args[0]);
  }
}
```

Now, this is appropriate use of inheritance because interfaces are contracts, and this particolar explicit implementation of the contract ensures it's used only when explicitly casted to interface. ie:

```
IBase fuel = new Fuel();
fuel.Perform(6); // works

Fuel fuel = new Fuel();
fuel.Perform(6); // won't compile, Perform doesn't exist in Fuel
```

#### Option 3: union type

You could create a simple union type, having 3 nullable references to your types. This also could work as a substitute to the interface option, performing the correct operation in a method

```cs
public readonly struct FuelTripPurchaseUnion
{
  readonly Fuel? _f; //null
  readonly Trip? _t; //null
  readonly Purchase? _p; //null

  public FuelTripPurchaseUnion (object original)
  {/* assign to the correct variable */}
  public FuelTripPurchaseUnion (Fuel fuel = default, Trip trip = default, Purchase purchase = default)
  {/* assign to the correct variable */
   // used like FuelTripPurchaseUnion(fuel: thefuel);
  }

  public void Perform()
  {
    // you can put your logic here and call the correct one...
  }
  
  public object Value()
  {
    // ...or you can return the correct value
  }
}
```

Obviusly you could optimize the code further with advanced type annotations as said in the comments but it's more advanced stuff (new to me too, that's why i'm not putting it in the answer)

##### Option 3.1: external library

As said in the previus comments, another option is to use an external library giving you something like a `OneOf<A,B,C>` object instead of implementing one yourself.

<del>but i won't suggest you use this one</del>

Comment: _"but i won't suggest you use this one."_ - why is that?

Comment: It's one more external dependendency you have to rely on and update, for something that can easily be solved with a couple more code lines. In the end it's more work in the long run for something really trivial.

Comment: Yes, but one can easily define a tagged-union as a single `readonly struct` by-hand.

Comment: True, but it's still 3 references per object. null references are still occupied memory, and personally i find it wasteful. Obviusly in the range of hundreads of references this becomes of importance... But still. It's an ok option i will edit it in

Comment: No... you can use a _single reference_ via type-punning via `FieldOffset` - which is permitted (even without `/unsafe`).

Comment: wow i didn't know this existed. I suppose it's 3 readonly `[FieldOffset(0)]` then

Comment: I've posted an answer demonstrating the concept, btw.

Answer (score 1):

### Quick-and-dirty tagged-union:

```cs
[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Explicit )]
public readonly struct Fuel_or_Trip_or_Purchase : IEquatable<Fuel_or_Trip_or_Purchase>, IEquatable<Fuel>, IEquatable<Trip>, IEquatable<Purchase>
{
    private const Byte TAG_DEFAULT  = 0;
    private const Byte TAG_FUEL     = 1;
    private const Byte TAG_TRIP     = 2;
    private const Byte TAG_PURCHASE = 3;
    
    public static implicit operator Fuel_or_Trip_or_Purchase( Fuel     fuel     ) => new Fuel_or_Trip_or_Purchase( fuel );
    public static implicit operator Fuel_or_Trip_or_Purchase( Trip     trip     ) => new Fuel_or_Trip_or_Purchase( trip );
    public static implicit operator Fuel_or_Trip_or_Purchase( Purchase purchase ) => new Fuel_or_Trip_or_Purchase( purchase );

    [FieldOffset(0)] private readonly Byte      tag;

    [FieldOffset(1)] private readonly Object    obj;
    [FieldOffset(1)] private readonly Fuel?     fuel;
    [FieldOffset(1)] private readonly Trip?     trip;
    [FieldOffset(1)] private readonly Purchase? purchase;

    public Fuel_or_Trip_or_Purchase( Fuel fuel )
    {
        this.obj      = fuel;
        this.purchase = null;
        this.trip     = null;
        
        this.fuel = fuel ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fuel));
        this.tag  = TAG_FUEL;
    }

    public Fuel_or_Trip_or_Purchase( Trip trip )
    {
        this.obj      = trip;
        this.purchase = null;
        this.fuel     = null;
        
        this.trip = trip ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(trip));
        this.tag  = TAG_TRIP;
    }

    public Fuel_or_Trip_or_Purchase( Purchase purchase )
    {
        this.obj  = purchase;
        this.fuel = null;
        this.trip = null;
        
        this.purchase = purchase ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(purchase));
        this.tag      = TAG_PURCHASE;
    }

    public Boolean TryGetFuel( [NotNullWhen(true)] out Fuel? fuel )
    {
        fuel = ( this.tag == TAG_FUEL ) ? this.fuel : null;
        return fuel != null;
    }

    public Boolean TryGetTrip( [NotNullWhen(true)] out Trip? trip )
    {
        trip = ( this.tag == TAG_TRIP ) ? this.trip : null;
        return trip != null;
    }

    public Boolean TryGetPurchase( [NotNullWhen(true)] out Purchase? purchase )
    {
        purchase = ( this.tag == TAG_PURCHASE ) ? this.purchase : null;
        return purchase != null;
    }

    public override Int32 GetHashCode() => HashCode.Combine( this.tag, this.obj.GetHashCode() );

    public override Boolean Equals( Object? obj )
    {
        if( obj is null )
        {
            return false;// this.tag == TAG_DEFAULT;
        }
        else if( obj is Fuel_or_Trip_or_Purchase other )
        {
            return this.Equals( other: other );
        }
        else if( obj is Fuel f )
        {
            return this.Equals( f: f );
        }
        else if( obj is Trip t )
        {
            return this.Equals( t: t );
        }
        else if( obj is Purchase p )
        {
            return this.Equals( p: p );
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Boolean Equals( Fuel_or_Trip_or_Purchase other ) => ( this.tag == other.tag ) && ( Object.ReferenceEquals( this.obj, other.obj ) );
    
    public Boolean Equals( Fuel?     f ) => ( this.tag == TAG_FUEL     ) && ( Object.ReferenceEquals( this.fuel    , f ) );
    public Boolean Equals( Trip?     t ) => ( this.tag == TAG_TRIP     ) && ( Object.ReferenceEquals( this.trip    , t ) );
    public Boolean Equals( Purchase? p ) => ( this.tag == TAG_PURCHASE ) && ( Object.ReferenceEquals( this.purchase, p ) );

    public TResult Match<TResult>(
        Func<Fuel,TResult>     whenFuel,
        Func<Trip,TResult>     whenTrip,
        Func<Purchase,TResult> whenPurchase,
    )
    {
        switch( this.tag )
        {
        case TAG_FUEL    : return whenFuel    ( this.fuel! );
        case TAG_TRIP    : return whenTrip    ( this.trip! );
        case TAG_PURCHASE: return whenPurchase( this.purchase! );
        default:
            throw new InvalidOperationException( "default(Fuel_or_Trip_or_Purchase)" );
        }
    }

    // Method forwarding:

    // Assuming Fuel, Trip and Purchase all have these members:

    public Decimal Cost => this.Match( f => f.Cost, t => t.Cost, p => p.Cost );
    public String  Name => this.Match( f => f.Name, t => t.Name, p => p.Name );
    // etc...
}
```

Used like so:

```cs
Fuel fuel0 = ..., fuel1 = ..., fuel2 = ...;
Trio trip0 = ..., trip1 = ..., trip2 = ...;
Purchase p = ...

List<Fuel_or_Trip_or_Purchase> list = new List<Fuel_or_Trip_or_Purchase>();

list.Add( fuel0 );
list.Add( trip0 );
list.Add( p );
list.Add( fuel1 );
list.Add( trip1 );

Decimal totalCost = list.Select( e => e.Cost ).Sum();
String  allNames  = String.Join( e => "\"" + e.Name + "\"", separator: "\r\n" );

// Or:

Decimal totalCost = 0M;
StringBuilder allNamesSB = new StringBuilder();

foreach( var e in list )
{
    totalCost += e.Cost;
    _ = allNamesSB.Append( '"' ).Append( e.Name ).Append( '"' ).AppendLine();
}

String allNames = allNamesSB.ToString();
```

Comment: Clever, but completely over-engineered for just putting items of different types into one list :D

Comment: That's why it's easier just to use `OneOf<...>` - but I also have this saved as a templated VS code-snippet.

Answer (score -2):

What you want is implemented through base class

```
public abstract class AbstractProcessor 
{
    public void CommonMethod() {} 
    public abstract void SpecificMethod() ;
} 

public class Fuel : AbstractProcessor 
{
    public override void SpecificMethod () 
    {
        // do fuel processing
    } 
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question - and it won't work if those types (`Fuel`, `Trip`, and `Purchase`) cannot share a supertype - and even so this is not an appropriate use of inheritance.

Comment: It does if you read it

Comment: No, it doesn't. You show how to create a base class, but not how to use a base class to actually solve the problem. And even then, the solution you've come up with is probably not a good solution. Just getting compiling code doesn't mean you've really written code that promotes maintainability and ease of consumption.